# Spring WebClient throw error based on response body

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am using Spring WebClient to call REST API. I  want to throw an error based on the response. For example, if there is an error (400) with body

```
{"error": "error message1 "}
```

then I want to throw an error with "error message1". Same way if there is an error(400) with the body

```
{"error_code": "100020"}
```

then I want to throw an error with error_cde 100020.  I want to do it in a non-blocking way.

```
public Mono<Response> webclient1(...) {

 webClient.post().uri(createUserUri).header(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(Mono.just(request), Request.class).retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, clientResponse -> {
        
                 //Error Handling
                
                }).bodyToMono(Response.class);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A body from ClientResponse should be extracted in a reactive way ([javadoc)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ClientResponse.html#bodyToMono-java.lang.Class-) and lambda in `onStatus` method should return another `Mono` ([javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.ResponseSpec.html#onStatus-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.function.Function-)). To sum up, take a look at below example

```
onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, response -> response
    .bodyToMono(Map.class)
    .flatMap(body -> {
        var message = body.toString(); // here you should probably use some JSON mapper
        return Mono.error(new Exception(message));
    })
);
```